# Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned 80070490 for URL 'http://mymachine:35609/'

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have written a webdriver test which I am trying to run via Jenkins distributed node. Here is the code snippet.

```java
WebDriver driver=null;
try {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D://IEDriver//IEDriverServer.exe");
  InternetExplorerDriverService service = InternetExplorerDriverService.createDefaultService();
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);
}catch(Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}

if(driver==null) {
    throw new Exception("Driver is not initialized");
}
driver.get(http://www.google.com);
```

I am able to run this code part via command prompt using **mvn -e clean test**. But the same command doesn't work when I try from jenkins, I am getting WebDriverException. Tried searching return code 80070490, but not much of help. Anyone faced this error before?

**Listening on port 17897
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned 80070490 for URL `'http://myserver:17897/'` (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)**